# Intermittent state of executing multiple queries using a Statement object

Tags: java, postgresql-9.3

I am executing multiple SQL statements using single Connection and Statement object as two processes.

1. Pre-process (Preprocess.java)
2. Post-process (Postprocess.java)

My Process steps are as follows,

1. Creating a Connection object and setAutoCommit() as false.
2. Creating a Statement object.
3. During pre-process executing the required SQL statements using the created Statement object.
4. Then for post-process i pass the same Statement object and executing the required SQL statements.
5. Finally commit the transaction (`connection.commit();`) and close the Connection,Statement objects.

My Problem is:

Sometimes the post-process executed statements are not reflected in database. That is, if i insert or update any records in post-process,those records are not available in database.

But the post-process execution is working fine without any exception.

The Probability of this case is 5 out of 1/(Which means 4 times working as i expected but 1 time its problematic).

Can any one point out the problem?

I am using Jdk 1.7 and Postgresql 9.3 version.

Comment: Are you properly catching and logging exceptions?

Comment: Yes of course i properly catch and logging exception. One more thing i did one mistake. Actually i have to commit the transaction after completing Postprocess. But i committed the transaction after completion of Preprocess. Hence the Postprocess records are not reflected in database.